# AngularJS Route Change Shows Next Template Before Previous One Goes Away

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angularjs application.

I cant figure out why the template for my second page briefly shows up below the home page template during route change?

Home Page: http://www.stalwil.com/admin/#/

Enter ZIP: 77056

During transition, watch the second page template show up before the home page template goes away. It's very annoying and I cant figure out why!

Second Page: http://www.stalwil.com/admin/#/enrollment

Here is my config for $routeProvider:

```
homeServices.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'zipController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/zip.html'
        })
    .when('/enrollment',
        {
            controller: 'enrollController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/enroll.html'
        })
    .when('/thankyou',
        {
            controller: 'thankyouController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/thankyou.html'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity for a [mcve].

Comment: I dont know what part of the code could be causing the issue....here is the routeprovider:

Comment: homeServices.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
  .when('/',
   {
    controller: 'zipController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/zip.html'
   })
  .when('/enrollment',
   {
    controller: 'enrollController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/enroll.html'
   })
  .when('/thankyou',
   {
    controller: 'thankyouController',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/thankyou.html'
   })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

Comment: You can also see it in my source code on the page of the links I provided.

Comment: I have seen similar issues when animating views, hope this gets answered.

Comment: After entering the zip and clicking the button are you making any kind of $http call?

Comment: Yes...I'm checking to see if the zip code entered is in the list of valid zip codes. It's a php script.